# get increasing variable from php to jquery

Tags: php, jquery, variables

how to pass a variable to jquery with php ? 
i have to call the jquery from html this is what is confusing me:

jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#pre-info').click(function() {
                $('#hide').slideToggle("fast");
        });
    });
```

now i want a $i after #pre-info and after #hide.

im calling the jqueryScript like this :

thank you.

Okay, here is more code :

```
<?php
    $i =0;

//Make some querys nd stuff

foreach ($all as $one) {    

//Here the event 1 is createt but the pre info gets increased with each event listet
echo "<div class='EVENT'><div id='pre-info$i'>";    


// get som other tables nd stuff
echo"</div><div id='hide$i' style='display:none;'>";

//now this part is hidden until i click on the pre-info

//hidden Stuff

$i++;
}

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pre-info').click(function() {
        var hiddenid=$(this).data('hiddenid');
        $('#'+hiddenid).slideToggle(); 
    });
});
</script>
```

it does still not work, did i miss anything? 
for me it looks like pre-info in this javascript needs a reference ( $i) as well ? 
maybe i just dont understand the jquery completly..

Comment: Why do you need to get the variable from php? What's the meaning of $x or $i ?

Comment: the reason is: I increase a div's id (div id='pre-info$i')each time i get new content a new id created.

so i want to hide or show a defined div (to show more info or content)

i want to be able to expand or minimize div specificaly by clicking on it. 

should i paste the whole code ?

Comment: Perhaps a little more code would help. But from what you say, you don't need php at all. You can just bump a variable each time you add a new div.

Comment: more code added. 
i dont understand the following :"
You can just bump a variable each time you add a new div"

Comment: At first I thought you had just one pre-info which would sequentially display each hidden div, but now I see that you have as many pre-infos as you have hidden divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so you have several hidden divs and for each one you also have a listener to toggle their visibility. The original list comes from php which in turn gets the data from a query.

You could use data attributes to link pre-infos to hidden elements:

```
$i =0;
foreach ($all as $one) {    
    echo "<div class='pre-info' data-hiddenid='hide$i'>click me</div>";    
    echo "<div id='hide$i' style='display:none;'> hidden stuff </div>";
    $i++;
}
```

then you just need one listener on jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.pre-info').click(function() {
        var hiddenid=jQuery(this).data('hiddenid');
        jQuery('#'+hiddenid).slideToggle(); 
    });
});
```

Hope it helps (**edit**, I wrapped the listener in the document ready event)

By the way, it seems to me you're reinventing the wheel. You could use [jQuery UI's accordions](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) or [Bootstrap collapsibles](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) with nice, crossbrowser transitions.

Comment: thank you, im very new to jquery and hardly understand it.
but i tried now to just paste the jQuery snip into the 
'<script type="text/javascript">' which is in the same file.

it doesnt do anything. 
and im sorry for not being precise enough on my question.

i think that this is also the reason why my question gets downrated. i will try on with this piece of jquery code. thanks

Comment: in jQuery you always need to wrap stuff inside the jQuery(document).ready() event. See my edit.

Comment: thank you, this seems to work! save.
ill correct my question with your answere, as soon as i have finished the project.

Answer (score 1):

If the JS is in .php file, you can just use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pre-info<?php echo $x; ?>').click(function() {
            $('#hide<?php echo $x; ?>').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

Your question does not contain enough information to give you more detailed answer, I'm afraid.

Comment: I had the jquery in another file. but now i will try to use this small function in the same file. let me try.

Answer (score 0):

you could embed the php variable you require into a hidden html attribute or a data attribute

Hidden Element HTML

```
<input type="hidden" id="someId" name="someName" value="<?php echo $someVariable?>"/>
```

Javascript

```
var someVar = $('#someId').val()
```

Data HTML

```
<div id="someId" data-some-var="<?php echo $someVariable?>"></div>
```

Javascript

```
var someVar = $("#someId").data("some-var")
```

Note that if you use data you must include the keyword "data" before whatever you decide to name the attribute

Comment: After looking over your edit and comments I actually don't think the code above would help in your case because you need something more dynamic. I would suggest trying to increment with javascript, and if thats not working look into [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax)